# Targeting Flash Player 11.2 - 11.4 APIs with the OpenLaszlo SWF11 runtime

Tags: flash, runtime, openlaszlo, flash-player-11, lzx

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949303) that there is an OpenLaszlo version capable of compiling LZX into SWF11 files for Flash Player 11.1. The SDK included with the flex4.6 branch of OpenLaszlo is - as we can tell by the name - Flex SDK 4.6.

In another discussion on the [Flash context menu in OpenLaszlo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518938/) it was mentioned that it is possible to target Flash Player APIs higher than 11.1 with the flex4.6 branch of OpenLaszlo.

What changes would have to be made the the flex4.6 branch to achieve this? Does that involve changing Java code within the LPS?

Comment: Note: Here is a link to the OL version supporting Flash 11.1 in case you don't already have it: http://download.openlaszlo.org/nightly/flex4.6/

Comment: I'm already using the flex4.6 branch for testing, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for the flex4.6 trunk version of OpenLaszlo it's required to make few small changes in the Java source code for the Flex SDK integration to target Flash Player 11.2+ APIs.

The affected files and folders are:

- Java classes org.openlaszlo.sc.SWF9External and org.openlaszlo.server.LPS
- The Flex SDK folder, where the corresponding playerglobal.swc needs to be added
- lps.properties file in WEB-INF/lps/config

I have that code ready on my machine, but I'm not willing to contribute any code to OpenLaszlo any more, therefore I won't be able to fix this in the flex4.6 branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe someone else is willing to work on that feature.